# Will SVN commands runs on TFS server

Tags: vb.net, svn, tfs

I had written a VB.NET application using `SVN commands` to synchronize source code between the `development SVN server( Subversion version 1.6.17)` and the `deployment SVN server( Subversion version 1.6.17)`.

Now the deployment SVN server is replaced withe the `TFS server`.

Will `TFS server` understands and execute the `SVN commands?`

Comment: I have used the SharpSVN.dll..                                                                                       http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/html/N_SharpSvn.htm

Comment: You should only have a single source code server. It I'd a production system that holds your organisational asset! Are you putting your business at risk by having two?

Answer (score 1):

No. To access TFS from your code you need to use the TFS API. You can have a look at this [sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286958.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)